# Append fragments to string

Tags: javascript, jquery

what I am trying:

```
args = ["4730/2", "17583/4"];

for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    console.log('here');
    url = args[i] + "/";
};

console.log(url);
```

I need to concatenate a string to generate something like this:

```
4730/2/17583/4/4730/2/17583/4
```

How can I do that?

http://jsfiddle.net/5npet/

Comment: You want to loop the array twice? It would be `url += ...`

Comment: Late update : http://stackoverflow.com/a/20637772/1636522 :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you already have the strings well formed in an array, you can simply [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) them using the separator you want:

```
var args = ["4730/2", "17583/4"];

var url = args.join('/');

console.log(url); // "4730/2/17583/4"
```

---

The error in your approach is that you overwrite the url variable at each iteration. Instead you should append the next part of the string like so:

```
var url = '';
for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    url += args[i] + "/";
};
```

After that, you still need to eliminate the last slash:

```
url = url.slice(0, str.length-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate way :

```
var args = ['4730/2', '17583/4'];
var url = [].concat(args, args).join('/');
```